# Packaging a Magento 1.9 extension is including all of Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have created my first Magento 1 extension (after business approval) and I want to upload it to the  Magento marketplace.

When I created the Magento extension package, it compressed the entire Magento source. I have three files in the `connect` folder:

- `try_home_1.0.0.tgz`
- `package.xml`
- `try_home.xml`

I have a few questions:

1. Does the package file include only the extension or all of Magento?
2. Is something wrong in my content path (see picture below)?
3. I found two other files in my `connect` folder: `package.xml` & `try_home.xml`. What are they for as we have only need to submit the `try_home.tgz` file to the Magento marketplace?
4. The Magento 1 package extension requires the `composer.json` file but I couldn't find that?

[image]

Comment: I have formatted your question to make it easier to read. You should describe the steps you are taking to package the extension.

Comment: I follow the below steps mentioned in magento package creatorpackage info
release info
author 
dependencies
contents
Still waiting for help?

Comment: Still stuck in this issue. Any help from magento expert?

Comment: It's difficult for us to answer the question. If you followed the instructions, it should have worked. So either there's a mistake in the instructions or you didn't follow them exactly. In either case we don't yet have enough information to help you. Did you take any shortcuts? Did you do all the steps, even the ones that didn't seem necessary? If you tell us exactly what you did step by step, maybe someone will see the problem.

Comment: Yes i follow the steps. Still stuck? Waiting reply from any magento expert

Answer (score 0):

I see your idea is to pack your Magento extension along with Magento as a Magento extension. You cannot do that. If you want to automatically deploy Magento and your extension, you could use a deployment tool.

I am not sure whether you are still looking for answers on the other questions raised, but just it case I am answering you briefly on them too:

1. The package should include only the files specific for your extension.
2. The line where you are including the Try/Home directory of your extension looks correct, however the rest of the lines are not. You should not attempt to include Magento core files in your package.
3. These two files contain the configuration settings of your extension, like name, version, description, etc. that you have provided to the extension packager. When the extension packager creates your package, it includes the package.xml file in the package too.
4. No, that is wrong. You are not required to include composer.json in your Magento 1 package.